# Open new tab besides last active non-pinned tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have a productivity web app (ClickUp) as a pinned tab in Firefox. Is it possible to configure Firefox (about:config or via extension) to pretend the pinned tab does not exist when opening a link in a new tab? Essentially, I wish the pinned tab behaved like a separate applicaiton.

**What currently happens:**

1. I am working in a second Firefox window on a different monitor (without pinned tabs).
2. I go to the pinned tab and middle-click a link.
3. A new tab opens beside the pinned tab or at the end of the window, depending on `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` setting.
4. I drag the tab from the main window to the second window.

**What I want to happen:**

1. I am working in a second Firefox window on a different monitor (without pinned tabs).
2. I go to my pinned tab and middle-click a link.
3. The new tab opens in the second window as if I'd clicked the link in an email client or some other external program.

I could probably run the "desktop" version of the productivity app and get the behavior I want. However, that would be another Electron+Chromium monstrosity, and I'm trying to support Firefox.

If you don't know how to do the above, does anyone with experience developing Firefox add-ons know if this is conceptually possible given the API's? I'm willing to try and develop my own extension, but it'd be nice if it's impossible before I sink a bunch of time into it.